# Block Reloc Tables in DLL Files

Tags: dll, compiler-construction, portable-executable

I write assemblers and compilers, and a couple of years was able to directly write PE+ EXE files.

Now I'm extending that to DLL files, and I'm slowly getting there. I'm just about to start generating a Block Relocation Table (I only found yesterday I needed one).

However, this table specifies relocations grouped within 4KB blocks. My question is, what happens if a relocatable field (it'll be 32- or 64-bits) crosses over into the next 4K block? That is, crosses the boundary from this 4096-byte virtual address page into the next.

For example, if a 64-bit relocatable field starts at offset 0xFFE in this page, and finishes at 0x005 in the next (2 bytes in one and 6 in the other). Will the relocation mechanism deal with that? If not, what do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I set up a test to see what would happen. This was an array of some 700 64-bit addresses, deliberately misaligned so that one word would cross a 4K boundary, and examined the block table produced by an existing linker. (Harder with code because the linker I used - gcc/ld - injected lots of code ot its own. Another reason I need my own solution).

And there was indeed a 64-bit relocation item that started at offset 0xFFB.

I guess this was the only pracical way of doing it (relocated fields in code will not usually be aligned), but it would be nice if the docs mentioned it.n